# Gradle error ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
```

When I change it to an updated dependency,
as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

The following build error occurs:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dailyspring.rejo.cpray"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

  //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
   // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0-beta'
    compile(group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-notifications-handler', version: '1.0.1', ext: 'jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.9@aar'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.github.hoang8f:android-flat-button:fa012e04ef'
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:+'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.balysv:material-ripple:v1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.futuresimple:android-floating-action-button:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.kikoso:AppRate-Android:1.0-RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      //  url  "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
        url "https://jitpack.io"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Instead Of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Try it once.

Comment: nope ! doesn't work !

Comment: can you please attach your build.gradle file code. it would be helpful to identify the problem.